# How to Create an HTML Bootstrap Tooltip for each option in Select tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4, tooltip

I have read many questions but didn't find any, which actually show an answer to my question.

How to can I create an HTML Bootstrap tooltip for each `option` in a `select` tag?

You can use the following dropdown for the purpose of this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<select>
    <option title="<h1>Tooltip 1</h1>">Hover over me</option>
    <option title="<h1>Tooltip 2</h1>">Hover over me</option>
    <option title="<h1>Tooltip 3</h1>">Hover over me</option>
    <option title="<h1>Tooltip 4</h1>">Hover over me<h1></option>
</select>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('option').tooltip({html:true});
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You can add the bootstrap-select picker than try, I have attached reference code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/61kbe55z/)

Comment: thanks @JayUkani! Can you please show an example without the live search?

Comment: You can add "liveSearch:false" in your select picker function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't found any way to show an HTML tooltip on an `option` tag. However, I found a more creative way to achieve exactly the same by using a Bootstrap dropdown.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // change dropdown button text when a dropdown option is clicked
  $('.dropdown-item').click(function() {
    $('.dropdown-toggle').text($(this).text());
  });

  // show html tooltip
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
    html: true,
    placement: "right"
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">First Option</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<em>Tooltip</em> <u>with</u> <b>HTML</b>">First Option</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<em>Tooltip</em> <u>with</u> <b>HTML</b>">Second Option</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<em>Tooltip</em> <u>with</u> <b>HTML</b>">Third Option</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
<select>
    <option class='ttip-opt' title="<h1>Tooltip 1</h1>">Hover over me</option>
    <option class='ttip-opt' title="<h1>Tooltip 2</h1>">Hover over me</option>
    <option class='ttip-opt' title="<h1>Tooltip 3</h1>">Hover over me</option>
    <option class='ttip-opt' title="<h1>Tooltip 4</h1>">Hover over me</option>
</select>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.ttip-opt').each(function(t){
            this.tooltip({html:true});
        });
    });
</script>
```

That is, you need to call tooltip on each option.